# How to understand the ip shown on my system?

Tags: java, networking

Hi actually I have not configured any static ip and i am not connected to any network. But some how this "169.254.74.143" ip is being displayed always. When I use "ipconfig" in command prompt but this also does not shows any ip on my system.

Actually I am sending an udp packet(java) from my system and i am taking the ip from that packet on the same system but that displays the above ip. I am not sure how this is happening.

Comment: If you're sending a UDP packet, it has to hit some network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your IP address has been automatically configured by your Operating System (I suppose you are running Windows ?)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_configuration_networking

EDIT : actually, it is more specifically called [Link Local addressing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address)